# Best metrics for neural network regression model in keras with multiple outputs

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, neural-network, metrics

I have built a neural network model with 495 inputs and 5 outputs which are to be predicted. When I did regression models with a single output, I liked using RMSE and R-squared as metrics. What similar metrics can be used for regression model with multiple outputs? I am already using MSE as the loss function so I suppose I should be using a different function as a metric.

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing a classification study, then you should use F1-score or like accuracy. I did not understand what you meant by 5 outputs? Is it like you are outputting 5 different regression series or something

Comment: I am doing regression model where I want the network to predict 5 different values associated with an object using the 495 features.

Comment: Oh ok then, it is a multivariate regression problem. Maybe you should look at cross-entropy kind of thing, so for multivariate, that would be helpful. Maybe this could help too https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/223256/tensorflow-cross-entropy-for-regression

Comment: Please phrase this as an explained conditional answer, in order to avoid the impression of asking a clarification question instead of answering (for which a comment should be used instead of an answer, compare https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead ). For example like "If your problem is ... then the solution is to .... because .... ."